Have problem to import TextLoader from langchain.document_loaders
I use this command 'from langchain.document_loaders import TextLoader' for import TextLoader. It used to work but now it is ERROR. It shows 'Error: No module named 'pydantic_v1.class_validators'; 'pydantic_v1' is not a package'  Anyone know how to fix it ? please !!  Using Langchain ==> langchain==0.0.266
enter image description here

Try update your langchain components first
pip install langchain --upgrade

and then try
from langchain_community.document_loaders import TextLoader

LangChain updates quite frequently, so older versions tend to get deprecated very fast.
